# Failing to build S4: Could not find property 'ext' on root project 's4'

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to build [S4](http://incubator.apache.org/s4/) from source. I've installed gradle and executed "gradle wrapper".

```
$ gradle wrapper
...
A problem occurred evaluating root project 's4'.
Cause: Could not find property 'ext' on root project 's4'.
...
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 's4'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:51)
...
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not find property 'ext' on root project 's4'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to say. My best guess is that you are using too old a Gradle version to generate the wrapper.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Yes, this was the case. Gradle from ubuntu repositories is quite old. I've installed the latest version and the project build has been successful. Please, post your comment as an answer.